# Constants in Penalty Function in Linear Optimization

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

A constant in a linear optimization problem does not influence the decision variables and thus may be discarded (as in this example: `max z = x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 + 37`).

In my example, I want to recommended users to other users in order to maximize the matches. A match is created when two users interact positively with one another. For this, I determined the match probabilities for every user with every other user. The maximization works perfectly fine.

However, every match obtained by a user in a period reduces the match probability of this user with every other user by `0.05` in the next period.
Given a user's match probability with another user is `70%` and the user obtained 4 matches in the period prior to the recommendation, the match probability would be only `50%`.

I want to consider this in the optimization. The approach is to extend the optimization with a penalty function and for this, calculate the expected number of matches every user may achieve in a period (this includes decision variables) and subtract the number of matches achieved in the last period (this is a fixed number and does not include decision variables). Given the number of expected matches is superior than the number of matches achieved last period, a penalty should be added (`-0.05` for every extra match).

The second term does only consist of a fixed number (`3` if a user obtained `3` matches in the prior period). However, the penalty does not improve my results. May this implementation even work or make sense?

Comment: It would probably help to see a formulation of your model (or at least of the key portions).